# Boot delay after upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10

Tags: boot, nouveau, 18.10

I have just updated from 18.04 to 18.10, and I faced a blank screen problem. Then I used the `nouveau.modeset=0` kernel boot option to boot. 
Now my laptop is not booting as fast as it did in 18.04, and some text is appearing on the screen after lines that start with a green OK like this:

```
[  OK  ] xxxxxxx .xxxx  
[  OK  ] xxxxxcc.xx.x.x.
[  OK  ] Started Set console scheme.  
[  OK  ] Created slice system-getty.slice.
```

[image]

I never saw this screen before. Please help me to boot my Ubuntu normally (no dual boot).

Specifications

Lenovo G40-35
  Processor: Intel Celeron (R) CPU N2830 @2.16GHZx2
  Graphics: Intel Bay Trail
  RAM:4GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Lenovo G40-35 doesn't have Nvidia graphics; it only has Intel discrete graphics. The graphics drivers for Intel integrated graphics are built-in in Ubuntu and you shouldn't install any other graphics drivers. That's why the `nouveau.modeset=0` kernel boot option slowed your boot time because that option is for Nvidia graphics only. Also the Nvidia proprietary graphic packages that you installed with `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` are not compatible with your computer's hardware and should be uninstalled. Run the following command to list the Nvidia packages that are installed:

```
dpkg -l nvidia* | grep ii
```

Uninstall all these packages with a command similar to `sudo apt remove first-file next-file last-file` and reboot with `sudo reboot` . Boot without adding the `nouveau.modeset=0` kernel boot option.

Comment: I checked the Lenovo G40-35's specs online, and it said that your laptop has Intel integrated graphics only.